# IE x remaining items

Tags: internet-explorer

I am developing a website and when I want to check it in IE, the page does not load completely. It says that 1 item remains to be loaded. I want to check what that is in order to fix it if is a bug.

Comment: Can you share the link to your website?

Comment: My website is local and on my laptop.

Comment: Can you confirm whether this happens in other browsers?

Comment: Have you got any external includes in your site (eg Google Analytics tracking code, etc etc)?

Comment: I don't have this problem in FF or Chrome. My code is part of a large framework. I have disabled the GA tracking code and I don't see any other scripts like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to check which of the requests has not ended properly

Comment: Thanx. Maybe I don't know how to use fiddler but it doesn't show local requests. I see requests from othere websites but not localhost.

Comment: See here: http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2008/01/10/tip-for-using-fiddler-on-localhost.aspx

Comment: Thanx, I checked it and there were 2 pictures missing. I removed them but still IE has the same problem. I checked fiddler with Firefox because when I open the page using IE, only 1 request appears in fiddler request list.